# Flipping pairs in compressed list in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've been banging my head around a problem for a few days now. I have been considering leaving it blank and waiting from the prof's answers but we still haven't received the answers from the previous assignment (3 months ago) and I really want to progress.

**THE SETUP:**

I made the following function than can compress lists according to repetitions:

```
def compress(list: List[T]) -> List[Tuple[T, int]] :
    """Returns the compressed list"""
    if len(list) == 1 :
        return [(list[0], 1)]
    result: List[Tuple[T, int]] = []
    count: int = 1
    i: int
    for i in range(1, len(list)) :
        if list[i] != list[i-1] :
            result.append((list[i-1], count))
            count = 1
        else :
            count = count + 1
            if i == len(list)-1 :
                result.append((list[i], count))
    return result

assert compress([3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
assert compress(['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']) == [('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

I also made the following decompressing function:

```
def decompress(code: List[Tuple[T, int]]) -> List[T] :
    """Returns the decompressed list"""
    return [value for (value, nb) in code for i in range(nb)]

assert decompress([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]) == [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
assert decompress([('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]) == ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

I then made a "flipping" function that flips every other item in a list (I know it's useless but hey, the exercice said I had to so...):

```
def flipping(liste:List[T]) -> List[T] :
    """Returns the list after flipping every other item"""
    length:int = len(liste)
    quotient: int = length // 2
    i:int
    result: List[T] = []
    for i in range(quotient) :
        resultat = result + [liste[2*i+1], liste[2*i]]
    if length % 2 == 1 :
        result = result + [liste[-1]]
    return result

assert flipping([1, 2, 3]) == [2, 1, 3]
assert flipping([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [2, 1, 4, 3]
assert flipping(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c']) == ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c']
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

I am now asked to make a function that can flip items the same way, but from a compressed list and WITHOUT decompressing it (yeah I know, no fun).

The only thing I know for sure is it should look like this:

```
def flipping_compressed(code:List[Tuple[T, int]]) -> List[Tuple[T, int]] :
    #does magic
    return result

assert flipping_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]
assert flipping_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 1)]
assert flipping_compressed([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

I've been trying for days and ended up every time with a huge function full of nested ifs that don't work anyway.
The whole assignment is supposed to be done in under two hours so I have obviously been missing something here.

I'd appreciate any help from more experienced comrads that enjoy a good problem :)

Cheers!

Comment: Can you explain what does flipping compressed mean? First decompress (perhaps virtually), and the flip pairs?

Comment: Think about it step by step. Suppose your original list starts with an even number of the same element, such that the compressed list starts with (even number, symbol). What will happen to those symbols when you "flip" them? What will the compressed result look like? Now, suppose it started with an odd amount instead; what will happen with the last element? Now, consider what happens to the second compressed chunk if there i) is; ii) is not something left over from the first chunk. Now try to generalize the logic.

Comment: You might want to clarify the description: you use "flipping" without defining it.  State that this involves swapping elements 2N and 2N+1.

Comment: @c2ig, This was a fun project. I have done all 4 things. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

This is called "run length encoding"; search the topic for resources.

This operates on simply partitioned pairs in the original list: positions 0 & 1, 2 & 3, 4 & 5, ...  To do the swapping without decompressing the list, you need to partition your list at all swap points.  For instance, given your compressed list

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
```

You need to break a single element anywhere it needs to be swapped with the adjacent element.  In this example,

```
(3, 4)   pos 0-3, no need to break
(1, 2)   pos 4-5, no need to break
(2, 1)   pos 6 .. needs a partner
(3, 2)   pos 7-8, needs the first element separated.
```

The one needed break gives you

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Swapping within a group does nothing; the only operations needed are where the pair elements are of different values.  That's (2, 1), (3, 1) here.

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

As it happens, this is your final result.

Let's look at another case you gave:

```
[('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

With required parity breaks, this becomes

```
[('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

Now, swap the adjacent pairs of even-odd index:

```
[('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('c', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

To get the final result, you now need to make a pass over the list, checking the items you swapped for "bonding" with the adjacent elements.  In this example, the only joining is the solo `c`, giving you

```
[('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('c', 5)]
```

This is the desired result.

I trust that you can work up some code from this algorithm outline.

Comment: In the second case, the rightmost had `('c', 4)` . Shouldnt that remain so the result ends with `('c', 5)`

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation. I learned something interesting today. Going to try and attempt answering the question now.

Comment: What happens when the flip compression input is `[(3, 4), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2)]` There are two items with single values `[3,3,3,3,1,2,3,3]`  Does this mean we flip `1` with `2` and leave the others as is. I assume so. The flip compression would then be `[3,3,3,3,2,1,3,3]` Am I correct? Or are we going to have `[3,3,3,1,3,3,2,3]`  or `[3,3,3,1,3,2,3,3]`?

Comment: What determines the swap is the index pairs: 0-1, 2-3, 4-5, etc.  In this case, we swap the 1 & 2, just as you suspect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
from typing import Sequence, Tuple, TypeVar, MutableSequence

T = TypeVar('T') 

def compress(items: Sequence[T]) -> Sequence[Tuple[T, int]]:
    compressed = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        last = 0
        if i > 0 and items[i] == items[i - 1]:
            last = compressed.pop()[1]
            
        compressed.append((items[i], last + 1))
    return compressed
    

assert compress([3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
assert compress(['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']) == [('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]

def flip(items: Sequence[T]) -> Sequence[T]:
    flipped = []
    n = len(items)
    it = itertools.islice(range(n), 0, None, 2)
    for i in it:
        if i + 1 < n:
            flipped.append(items[i + 1])
        flipped.append(items[i])
    return flipped
    
assert flip([1, 2, 3]) == [2, 1, 3]
assert flip([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [2, 1, 4, 3]
assert flip(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c']) == ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c']
    

def flip_compressed(items: MutableSequence[Tuple[T, int]]) -> Sequence[Tuple[T, int]]:
    flipped = []
    n = len(items)
    
    def append_or_merge(v: T, i: int) -> None:
        x = i
        if flipped and flipped[-1][0] == v:
            x += flipped.pop()[1]
        
        flipped.append((v, x))
        
    
    for i in range(n):
        val, cnt = items[i]
        if cnt == 0:
            continue
        times = cnt // 2
        rem = cnt % 2
    
        if times > 0:
            append_or_merge(val, times * 2)
        if rem == 1:
            if i + 1 < n:
                nxt_val, nxt_cnt = items[i + 1]
                append_or_merge(nxt_val, 1)
                items[i + 1] = (nxt_val, nxt_cnt - 1)
            append_or_merge(val, 1)
    
    return flipped
    
assert flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]
assert flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 1)]
assert flip_compressed([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a great project to work on. Thank You for posting the question. I have upvoted and bookmarked your question.

I got all 4 processes correctly. Here's my code for the 4 items:

1. compressed the list
2. decompress the list [list comprehension]
3. flipped the items in the list when the sequence changed
4. flipped the compressed list when the sequence changed. Obviously did it without decompressing

Here's the code for all 4 items. I also printed the values to ensure it does the compression, decompression, and flipping correctly. The output of this program is also added to the bottom of each code section.

## compress the list

```
def compress(lst):
    total = 1
    compressed = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i-1] != lst[i]:
            compressed.append((lst[i-1],total))
            total = 1
        else:
            total += 1
            if i == len(lst)-1: compressed.append((lst[i],total))
    return compressed

assert compress([3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
assert compress(['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']) == [('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]

print ('Run Length Encoding : compression :')
print ()
print ("[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]")
print (compress([3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]))
print ()
print ("['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']")
print (compress(['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']))
print ()
```

Output for above code:

```
Run Length Encoding : compression :

[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]

['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']
[('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

## decompress the list

```
def decompress(lst):
    return [a[0] for a in lst for i in range(a[1])]

assert decompress([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]) == [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
assert decompress([('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]) == ['a','a','c','c','c','d','c','c','c','c']

print ('Run Length Encoding : decompression :')
print ()
print ("[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]")
print (decompress([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]))
print ()
print ("[('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]")
print (decompress([('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]))
print ()
```

Output for above code:

```
Run Length Encoding : decompression :

[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]

[('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('c', 4)]
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

## flipping the values in the list when value changes

```
def flipping(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst)-1:
        if lst[i] != lst[i+1]:
            lst[i],lst[i+1] = lst[i+1],lst[i]
        i+=2
    return lst

assert flipping([1, 2, 3]) == [2, 1, 3]
assert flipping([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [2, 1, 4, 3]
assert flipping(['a','a','a','a','c', 'c','d','c','c']) == ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c']

print ('Run Length Encoding : flipping :')
print ()
print ("[1, 2, 3]")
print (flipping([1, 2, 3]))
print ()
print ("[1, 2, 3, 4]")
print (flipping([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print ()
print ("['a','a','a','a','c', 'c','d','c','c']")
print (flipping(['a','a','a','a','c', 'c','d','c','c']))
print ()
```

Output for above code:

```
Run Length Encoding : flipping :

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]

['a','a','a','a','c', 'c','d','c','c']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c']
```

## flip the compressed list without decompressing

```
def flip_compressed(lst):    
    i = 0
    j = len(lst)
    flst = [[a[0],a[1]] for a in lst] #convert tuples to lists for ease of manipulation

    while i < len(flst)-1:   #flip based on position. flip only if value is 1
        if flst[i][1] == 1:
            if flst[i+1][1] > 1:
                flst[i+1][1] -=1
                flst.insert(i+1,[flst[i+1][0],1])
            flst[i][0],flst[i+1][0] = flst[i+1][0],flst[i][0]
        i +=2
    i = 0
    while i < len(flst)-1:    #check if we need to merge any of the compressed items
        if flst[i][0] == flst[i+1][0]:
            flst[i][1] += flst[i+1][1]
            flst.pop(i+1)
        else:
            i+=1

    flst = [(a[0],a[1]) for a in flst] #convert it back to tuples
    return flst

assert flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]
assert flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]) == [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 1)]
assert flip_compressed([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]) == [(3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]

print ('Run Length Encoding : flip compressed :')
print ()
print ("[('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]")
print (flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]))
print ()
print ("[('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]")
print (flip_compressed([('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]))
print ()
print ("[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]")
print (flip_compressed([(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]))
print ()
```

Output for above code:

```
Run Length Encoding : flip compressed :

[('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]

[('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 1)]

[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```